# How to get calculated value from cell formula in Maatwebsite Laravel Excel?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

In excel, I have 3 columns named `Total`, `Payment Released`, and `Payment Return`. To calculate `Payment Return`, I added a formula inside it which is `=U2-G2`.

> Note: U2 is `Payment Released` and G2 is `Total`.

I have read the documentation of Maatwebsite Laravel Excel for importing from excel to the database, and the data inserted successfully. But when I check the database, the `payment_return` column is all filled by zero `0`. When I do `dd($row['Payment Return']`, it shows not the value it contains in the excel, but the formula itself.

[image]

How do I solve this, please?

P.S: Have read [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/import/calculation.html) too, but I have no idea where the `import.php` file is, and where should I write the function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey man, did you get this resolved? having the same problem

Comment: Check my answer, thanks. Hope your code run well 

Answer (score 26):

documentation is terrible but found the fix:
add

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;
```

and

```
class MyCustomImport implements WithCalculatedFormulas
```

in ths Imports/MycustomImports.php file and formulas are now calculated when importing so we get the actual value.

Comment: To add to this, if you are using `toArray` to process the data, you need to specify the `calculateFormulas: true` parameter, else dd will still show the formula.
`$row->toArray(null, true);` The source of toArray: `public function toArray($nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = false, $formatData = true, ?string $endColumn = null)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612920/how-to-process-excel-sum-formulas-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the right answer but I was in production, so I take an alternative way. I inserted the values from the excel in my PHP file and manually calculated it. It looks like

`$valOne = $row['cell_U2'];`

`$valTwo = $row['cell_G2'];`

`$result = $valOne-$valTwo;`

The variable `$result` is what I inserted into the database. By doing this, you can use formulas in excel instead, but It will not be considered in the system.