# How to process excel SUM formulas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, excel-formula

[image: image displaying a die dump of the excel file imported]

the above image is a display of the dd method in laravel after importing my excel file. the problem is after proccessing it, other columns gets stored but line **23 and 25** get stored as 0, but if viewed with the microsoft excel software it shows the exact number that it suppose to.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use DB;

class SummaryImport implements ToCollection
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows){
        unset($rows[0]);
        unset($rows[1]);
        unset($rows[2]);
        unset($rows[3]);
        unset($rows[4]);
        unset($rows[5]);
        unset($rows[6]);

        foreach ($rows as $key) {
            // dd($key);
            if($key[1] !== null){
                DB::table('summary_uploads')->insert(
                    [
                        'lga' => $key[2], 
                        'reg_voters' => $key[3],
                        'accred_voters' => $key[4],
                        'A' => $key[5],
                        'AA' => $key[6],
                        'AAC' => $key[7],
                        'ADC' => $key[8],
                        'ADP' => $key[9],
                        'APC' => $key[10],
                        'APGA' => $key[11],
                        'APM' => $key[12],
                        'APP' => $key[13],
                        'BP' => $key[14],
                        'LP' => $key[15],
                        'NNPP' => $key[16],
                        'NRM' => $key[17],
                        'PDP' => $key[18],
                        'PRP' => $key[19],
                        'SDP' => $key[20],
                        'YPP' => $key[21],
                        'ZLP' => $key[22],
                        'total_valid_votes' => $key[23],
                        'rejected_votes' => $key[24],
                        'total_votes_cast' => $key[25],
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**total_valid_votes** and **total_votes_cast** keeps getting stored as 0

Comment: is there no way PHP can process this formulas or any laravel package can?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get calculated value from cell formula in Maatwebsite Laravel Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316180/how-to-get-calculated-value-from-cell-formula-in-maatwebsite-laravel-excel)

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Tobias k. ,No explicit example was shown in your suggestion and also suggestion by avn is quite misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing the `WithCalculatedFormulas`, it solved this problem. Here is an example

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;

//notice the former and the latter "class" 
class SummaryImport implements ToCollection,WithCalculatedFormulas
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows){
        unset($rows[0]);
        unset($rows[1]);
        unset($rows[2]);
        unset($rows[3]);
        unset($rows[4]);
        unset($rows[5]);
        unset($rows[6]);

        foreach ($rows as $key) {
            if($key[1] !== null){
                DB::table('summary_uploads')->insert(
                    [
                        'lga' => $key[2], 
                        'reg_voters' => $key[3],
                        'accred_voters' => $key[4],
                        'A' => $key[5],
                        'AA' => $key[6],
                        'AAC' => $key[7],
                        'ADC' => $key[8],
                        'ADP' => $key[9],
                        'APC' => $key[10],
                        'APGA' => $key[11],
                        'APM' => $key[12],
                        'APP' => $key[13],
                        'BP' => $key[14],
                        'LP' => $key[15],
                        'NNPP' => $key[16],
                        'NRM' => $key[17],
                        'PDP' => $key[18],
                        'PRP' => $key[19],
                        'SDP' => $key[20],
                        'YPP' => $key[21],
                        'ZLP' => $key[22],
                        'total_valid_votes' => $key[23],
                        'rejected_votes' => $key[24],
                        'total_votes_cast' => $key[25],
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**$key[23]** and **$key[25]** no longer storing as 0 but as the calculated value.

Thanks to **Tobias k.** comment, I only provided a more explaining example